# MPI microsoft command line compile x86 conflict link error

Tags: c++, command-line, mpi

From the Developer Comand Prompt for VS 2013, I try to compile and link
a simple test MPI program.

Using the two batch files copied below, I type:

```
mpicc mpi
mpicl mpi
```

From the link step I get the following error message:

mpi.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target m
achine type 'x64'

I have been following the note on "How to compile and run a simple MS-MPI 
program:" at:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowshpc/archive/2015/02/02/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-ms-mpi-program.aspx

I see the (x86) which seems to conflict with the fact that I am compiling
sixty-four bits but I don't know what else to specify as that is where
MPI install put the files in question.

Here is the mpicc.bat batch file

```
cl /I"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\x64" /I /I"c:\program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\windows\v8.1A\Include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\Include" /c %1.cpp
```

Here is the mpicl.bat batch file

```
link /machine:x64 /out:%1.exe /dynamicbase "msmpi.lib" /libpath:"c:\program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64" /libpath:"c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft\Visual Studio 12.0\VC\LIB\amd64" /libpath:"c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\x64" %1%.obj
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question on askmpi@microsoft.com.  They responded that I should
use a different command prompt in the Visual Studio Tools folder.

When I used the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt, the link step now works fine.